# Is it possible to connect my ASP.NET MVC windows authentication to another domain

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication

I am not in system administration, but our current project requires me to do some system admin tasks. I have the following:-

- Asp.net MVC web application that uses windows authentication only.
- On our dev environment I have both the AD and the ASP.NET MVC web application on the same machine. So I could connect asp.net mvc with AD without any problem. And I use the below code to retrieve the AD users ,besides having the users login to the application using their AD credentials:-

> ```
>   public List<DomainContext> GetADUsers(string term=null)
>             {
>                 List<DomainContext> results = new List<DomainContext>();
>                 string ADServerName = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADServerName"];
>                 using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, ADServerName))
>                 using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
>                 {
>                     var searchResults = searcher.FindAll();
>
>
> foreach (Principal p in searchResults)
>                     {
>                        if (term == null || p.SamAccountName.ToString().ToUpper().StartsWith(term.ToUpper()))
>                        {
> ```

- Now I moved the asp.net mvc web application to our staging server. And on the staging server the AD is on another machine and also on different domain.

So my questions are:-

1. How I can force the asp.net MVC web application , to authnticate the users against the AD on the remote server. I mean From where I can set which domain the asp.net mvc should connect to ?
2. What are the requirements to allow the `DomainContext` on asp.net mvc web application, to retrieve the users from the AD on remote server. Should both domains be joined together? Or should the user on both machine have the required permissions..

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set your connection string something like:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="TestDomain1ConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://testdomain1.test.com/CN=Users,DC=testdomain1,DC=test,DC=com" />    
</connectionStrings>
```

You can find full walk through here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650307.aspx

Comment: thanks for the reply, but the link you provide is talking about form authentication, while in my case I am using windows authentication .. are the link valid for both cases?